# Cleaning up .vim/after/ftplugin directory

Tags: vim

I was in the process of cleaning up my `.vim` directory and noticed that I have a bunch of similar stuff in `.vim/after/ftplugin`. I put filetype related stuff in there, like tab settings etc. For example this is `.vim/after/ftplugin/sh.vim` contents:

```
setlocal nowrap
setlocal expandtab
setlocal tabstop=8
setlocal softtabstop=4
setlocal shiftwidth=4
setlocal formatoptions-=ro
```

I have around ~10 of those for some most frequently used filetypes I have to deal with.

Recently I had similar situation with stuff in `.vim/ftdetect` which I managed to replace just one file `.vim/filetype.vim`. **So, now I am wondering if I could take similar approach to `.vim/after/ftplugin` stuff?** E.g. combine to just one file.

Maybe it does not make sense and I should leave this as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What purpose does this cleaning up serve? If you understand the various locations that Vim uses, having your configuration spread (to the *right* places) makes it actually easier to locate, and achieves a nice separation of concerns (in contrast to the antipattern of one huge `~/.vimrc` file that contains a mixed jumble of stuff).

Especially for filetype-specific stuff (which is only loaded on demand), the performance improvements of one large vs. many small files is also negligible (and with caching in modern operating systems shouldn't be an issue at all with Vim).

The `.vim/after/ftplugin/` location is used to override or extend default filetype settings. Your example indent and formatoptions settings fit this perfectly. **Keep doing that!**

With regards to `ftdetect/*.vim` vs. `filetype.vim`, I put my personal customizations in the latter, but keep any plugin / external detections in the former.

Comment: OK, Ingo, seems that now is a good point to stop cleaning up things in my ~/.vim and leave after/ftplugin alone. I started clenup because I noticed my ~/.vim had accumulated lots of stuff over the years and lot of it was not serving purpose and of course many different files in many places looked a lot like a mess.